# How do i pass an int from html file (template) to py file (flask)?

Tags: javascript, python, database, flask, transfer

I'm trying to make a local site (just to get the basics of flask) and I want to click a button and store the number of clicks in a txt file. I have the button clicking down and can send the number of clicks TO the html file, but I have no idea how to send that int back to the py file in order to update the txt file.

In the following code I use localStorage as a stand-in but I want it to get the data from the txt file and send the data back to the txt file when the button is pressed.

html file-

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonPress()">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = {{ sClicks }}

    localStorage.setItem('sClicks', clicks);
    updateText();

    function buttonPress(){
        clicks += 1;
        localStorage.setItem('sClicks', clicks);
        updateText();
    }

    function reset(){
        localStorage.clear();
        clicks = 0;
        localStorage.setItem('sClicks', clicks);
        updateText();
    }

    function updateText(){
        document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('sClicks');
    }
</script>
</body>
```

py file-

```
app = Flask(__name__)
clicks = open('Clicks.txt').read()

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return render_template('index.html', sClicks=clicks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='my ip adress')
```

Comment: The only way to pass data between the frontend (browser) and the backend (your flask server) is through http requests, meaning you would have to create a POST or a PUT route that is used to send data from the browser to flask.

You could either do this by 1. create a POST route where the data is sent and re-render the html page everytime the button is clicked. 2. pass the data between the browser and the server using XHR requests.

Comment: are there any tutorials or guides you know of that can help me set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of how you could send the event using a javascript xhr request that sends a post request to the /clicks route.

Note that in the POST request i haven't added any data to the request body but merely just use the fact that the route is called with a POST request as a notification that the counter should increase by 1.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from os import path

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/clicks", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def click_collector():
    # POST logic
    if request.method == "POST":
        current_count = read_click_db()
        if current_count is not None:
            new_count = int(current_count) + 1
            return write_click_db(new_count)
        return write_click_db(1)

    # GET logic
    elif request.method == "GET":
        current_count = read_click_db()
        if current_count is not None:
            return current_count
        return "0"


def read_click_db() -> str:
    if not path.isfile("Clicks.txt"):
        print("File doesn't exist")
        return
    with open("Clicks.txt", "rt") as f:
        click_counter = f.readline()
        f.close()
    return click_counter


def write_click_db(counter: int):
    with open("Clicks.txt", "wt") as f:
        f.write(str(counter))
        f.close()
        return str(counter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=5000)
```

Execute the below JavaScript function in the browser console.

```
function notify_click_event() {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/clicks")
    req.send()
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, i can send data back and forth, but in the python script where it says "# Code to update click counter here" how do i acsess the data sent from the frontend?

Comment: It depends. In the above example, i do not care about sending any body in the POST request, but instead counting the actual number of requests received on that listener. Updating a bit now to show how i mean

Of course, if you are interested in sending additional data with the POST request body, you could do that using e.g. json and then parse the request body in flask using request.get_json()

Comment: ok i did some testing with the code and for some reason when notify_click_event() is called on the front end, the click_collector() function isn't called on the back end

Comment: Have you copy pasted all or is something different? Can you confirm with e.g. a console.log in the javascript code that the function is actually executed in the browser?

Comment: yes notify_click_event() is definitely being called, i added ```document.getElementById("carrier").innerHTML = "called";``` and the text does change when being called.

Comment: Ok, and what about your flask server, is it running on localhost:5000? like app.run(host="localhost", port=5000) in my example above. Sorry for repeating, but have you copy-pasted the python code above completely?

Comment: yep, changing to host="localhost", port=5000 worked! sorry I didn't copy the whole thing :/

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck with your project :)